# Visualizing polygon and point data?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, visualisation

As part of pilot project, we have collected basic/rudimentary Household survey in one district. We have both Polygon and point data.Attributes of the database include, No of people living in the house, males, females, ownership of the house, private-public properties, structure of the house, quality of the house, etc....

I am open to suggestions on how best to visualize/ map the data (Methods). I am familiar with ArcGIS Desktop and QGIS. Recently i have started using some web data visualization tools like ArcGIS online, cartodb, Mapbox. but i am interested in Desktop solutions as i will be printing those maps for a forum.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add some more information about the data. A screenshot of the polygon and point dataset would help. Do you want to vizualize all attributes of the two datasets at the same time?

Comment: Thank you @Michael. The point data set is derived from the polygon features. I don't want to visualize them at the same time. I was thinking may be in different ways. The data is first of its kind to be collected in this country as it is emerging from civil war, It is not a full Household survey but a pilot and will be presented in an urban analysis forum.

Comment: It is important to clearly define your objectives before making any maps.  Too much information detracts from the message you are trying to convey.  What are you trying to convey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to work in Census Bureau in my country and we did this kind of thematic maps. You could try making a thematic map for each of the variables you have. I would suggest you collect streets also, you can do that using OpenStreetMap maybe and exporting to a GIS format afterwards.

For the quantitative measures you could have a legend and use a scale e.g.

- Quality of the House
- Excellent Condition - Green
- Regular Condition - Yellow
- Bad Condition - Red